# Clojure performance, large looping over large vectors

Tags: performance, loops, clojure

I am performing element-wise operations on two vectors on the order of 50,000 elements in size, and having unsatisfactory performance issues (a few seconds).  Are there any obvious performance issues to be made, such as using a different data structure?

```
(defn boolean-compare
  "Sum up 1s if matching 0 otherwise"
  [proposal-img data-img]
  (sum
  (map
    #(Math/abs (- (first %) (second %)))
    (partition 2 (interleave proposal-img data-img)))))
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
(apply + (map bit-xor proposal-img data-img)))
```

Some notes:

- `map`ping a function to several collections uses an element from each as the arguments to the function - no need to `interleave` and `partition` for this.
- If your data is 1's and 0's, then `xor` will be faster than absolute difference

Timed example:

```
(def data-img (repeatedly 50000 #(rand-int 2)))
(def proposal-img (repeatedly 50000 #(rand-int 2)))
(def sum (partial apply +))
```

After warming up the JVM...

```
(time (boolean-compare proposal-img data-img))
;=> "Elapsed time: 528.731093 msecs"
;=> 24802

(time (apply + (map bit-xor proposal-img data-img)))
;=> "Elapsed time: 22.481255 msecs"
;=> 24802
```

Answer (score 5):

You should look at adopting [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api) if you are interested in good performance for large vector operations.

In particular, the [vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj) library (a core.matrix implementation) has some very fast implementations for most common vector operations with `double` values.

```
(def v1 (array (repeatedly 50000 #(rand-int 2))))
(def v2 (array (repeatedly 50000 #(rand-int 2))))

(time (let [d (sub v2 v1)]    ;; take difference of two vectors
     (.abs d)                 ;; calculate absolute value (mutate d)
     (esum d)))               ;; sum elements and return result

=> "Elapsed time: 0.949985 msecs"
=> 24980.0
```

i.e. under `20ns` per pair of elements - that's pretty quick: you'd be hard pressed to beat that without resorting to low-level array-fiddling code.

Comment: Example of array-fiddling (w/o checks for same length) for use on `int-array`s: `(defn xor-sum [^ints xs, ^ints ys] (areduce xs i ret (int 0) (unchecked-add ret (bit-xor (aget xs i) (aget ys i)))))`
`